# Open modal in another controller with ng-include

Tags: javascript, cordova, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I've this issue when I'm trying to open a modal in AngularJS with phonegap.

I'm checking the connection from device, if device is offline, I need to open a modal.

I have this code on my index.html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" >

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var $injector = angular.bootstrap(document, ['sms']);
        var $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
        var scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
        var DeviceCtrl = $controller("DeviceCtrl", {$scope: scope});
        scope.checkDevice(device.uuid, navigator.network.connection.type);
    }

</script>
...

 <div ng-controller="ModalCtrl" ng-include="'app/partials/modals.html'">
```

That script call `checkDevice` function on `DeviceCtrl`. OK at this point.

```
DeviceCtrl:

function DeviceCtrl($scope, $window, Device, $rootScope) {

$scope.checkDevice = function (deviceUuid, networkState) {

    if (networkState == 'none') {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('openConectionless');
    }  
}
```

And my ModalCtrl:

```
function ModalCtrl($scope) {
$scope.$on('openConectionless', function() {
    angular.element("#conectionModal").modal("show");

});
```

}

The `openConectionless` listener is called, but the `angular.element("#conectionModal").modal("show");` doesn't affect the modal.

NOTE: If I put the `conectionModal` div on index.html and call `angular.element("#conectionModal").modal("show");` on `DeviceCtrl` instead of `$rootScope.$broadcast('openConectionless');` , the modal open. 
But I want to move the modal code to another html to make the code clean. So I create the ModalCtrl.

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: try using `src` attribute `ng-include src="'app/partials/modals.html'"`

Comment: @charlietfl I put `src=` like you recommend, but doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: does `id=conectionModal` show up in live html in browser console? Has `modal` been initialized? If  `id=conectionModal` was in DOM originally and worked, it is now being AJAX loaded and bootstrap or other modal plugin won't find it automatically if being auto initialized on page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using `bootstrap` as modal plugin and modal is auto initialized on page load when the html is within index.html based on `bootstrap` `data` attribute in markup.

Since `ng-include` requires an AJAX request, the modal html doesn't exist when modal plugin runs initially so your modall is never intialized.

You could create a simple directive that will run the initialization code and add an attribute to the modal markup for that directive

Comment: You answer make sense. But I try to build a directive like in this blog: http://www.grobmeier.de/twitter-bootstrap-modal-angular-js-29082012.html#.UVcvEJPkt8E but I really don't know how to call the modal from a controller, without using a button.

Comment: Did you have some example to build the directive to run the incialization code? Thanks.

Comment: see this demo....is fairly simple for basic implemntation  http://plnkr.co/edit/Ci90H1kW8KDtaG8oUETZ

Comment: Thanks, the html is loaded normally and works fine. But, can I open the modal without having this button? Like a trigger in controller? like angular.element("#id").modal('show');?

Comment: sure... I just got it running with the bootstrap automatic initialized button. Here's a version that uses `ng-click` to call a controller function to open it  http://plnkr.co/edit/pqhGqNfGSeiYNe15eZ6R

Comment: Sorry for the 1 year delay =)